# Using dropzone.js allow selecting one file at a time but can upload many

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js
The Issue is i want to allow user to select only one file at a time (when selecting from pop-up window/dialogue-box)
And when one is uploaded he can add more but with above restriction
Will you guys please help me out

I tried `maxFiles:1` but what it does it allow user to select one file from pop-window(perfect), but after that, if a user tries to add another one it crashes,

> A new section for uploading image opens (an image preview, status bar and delete button (preview remains null))Upload button turns to loading and it keeps loading and loading

And on inspecting

> inspecting that second loading image section in Google console

I got that it is giving an error message that you can't upload more file...

`<div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage="">You can not upload any more files.</span></div>`

Please help me out, I shall be very thankful

Comment: What does `it crashes` mean, exactly?  `And on inspecting` - inspecting what?  Is this something on the console?  Some msg displayed on your Dropzone?  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).